# Fatal Error Step 8 of Setup: Does not support MySQL versions below 5.6

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

So I (believe) that I have gotten to step 8 of the installation guide for azerothcore (on windows). But when I run either authserver or worldserver, I get this message:

```
C:\Users\Ethan\azerothcore\src\common\Database\DatabaseWorkerPool.cpp:22 in DatabaseWorkerPool<class WorldDatabaseConnection>::DatabaseWorkerPool FATAL ERROR:
AzerothCore does not support MySQL versions below 5.6
```

But I have MySQL 5.6, so I am not sure what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the same error when trying with MySQL 5.7 ?

Comment: Yes, I just got MySQL 5.7 and went through the whole process again - same result.

Comment: are you sure that your AC conf is not pointing to an older instance of MySQL ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "AC conf". If you mean worldserver.conf/authserver.conf, then I believe so. I did change the port of worldserver.conf to 3306 and updated acore_auth realmlist to reflect that, if that means anything. But even when that is the case, the same error arises.

Comment: There is this section in conf/config.sh you might be thinking of:
```
#
# Example:
#        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysql.exe"
#        "/usr/bin/mysql"
#        "mysql"
#
```
Mentioned in the database setup section. But I didn't mess with this commented part or make anything of it, since I wasn't sure what it was supposed to be an example of.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. It's very weird. Have you tried installing MySQL completely from your system (erasing any previous version) and then installing MySQL 5.7 ?

Comment: That is what I did a couple of hours ago (I believe). I uninstalled MySQL 5.6 using the MySQL uninstall tool. Then I installed MySQL 5.7 and followed steps 4+ again as necessary.
Would it make a difference if I changed every occurrence of "127.0.0.1" to my IPv4 addres?

Comment: if by "IPv4" you mean your external address, no you should use your local one

Comment: Okay. I will try to restart the whole process and see if that makes a difference to the end result, rather than starting from step 4.

Comment: Hi. I reset everything and started fresh, and I am still running into the exact same problem. So now I am really not sure what it could be.

Comment: Please use 5.7 or MariaDB 10.4:/

Comment: Hi. Like I said, I have switched to using MySQL 5.7, and the problem is still occurring. If you can think of anything else that might be causing the problem, I would be happy to provide my details on any part of what I have done so far.

Comment: If it helps, here is the code mentioned by the error message I reported above:

DatabaseWorkerPool<T>::DatabaseWorkerPool() :

_mqueue(new ACE_Message_Queue<ACE_SYNCH>(2*1024*1024, 2*1024*1024)),

_queue(new ACE_Activation_Queue(_mqueue))

{

    memset(_connectionCount, 0, sizeof(_connectionCount));

    _connections.resize(IDX_SIZE);


    WPFatal(mysql_thread_safe(), "Used MySQL library isn't thread-safe.");

    WPFatal(mysql_get_client_version() >= MIN_MYSQL_CLIENT_VERSION, "AzerothCore does not support MySQL versions below 5.6");

}
Sorry, not sure how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by using a too old version of libmysql.dll. Make sure it comes from a MySQL install of version 5.6+. You'll find it in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.X\lib", just copy it from there and paste it to whatever folder you launch AzerothCore from.